# powershell - adding folder path with another path

Tags: powershell

```
$path = "c:\folder a"
$destFolder = "C:\" 
$subFolder = "\folder c\folder d\" 
$file = "file.txt" 

$dir = Get-ChildItem $path | select -first 10 | Sort-Object -Property CreationTime 

[array]::Reverse($dir) 

$dir | format-table FullName  

$fullPath = @() 

ForEach ($i in $dir) { 
    $fullPath += $i + $subFolder + $file 
} 

$i = 0 

while ($i -lt $fullPath.Count) { 

    $exists = Test-Path $fullPath[$i] 

    if ($exists){ 
        Copy-Item -Path $fullPath[$i] -Destination $destFolder 
        break 
    } 
    $i++ 
}
```

having trouble getting &fullpath to work

edit:

&fullpath displays all the folder in the directory then adds the subfolder+file at the end.

I want it to take the 1 file path at a time from &dir and add the subfolder+file

sorry if I haven't explained it very well.

Im a total beginner at this kind of stuff

Comment: What, exactly, is wrong? What do you expect to happen and what really happens?

Comment: A generic hint, review the logic behind your code. For example you sort your array by a property then you reverse it. Isn't simpler sorting descending? `dir = xxx | Sort-Object -Property CreationTime -Descending`.
Then you use `foreach` to compute a path and instead of doing the other actions there you save the path and cycle through it using a `while`. Does it make sense? `ForEach ($i in $dir) {  $fullPath += $i + $subFolder + $file; $exists = Test-Path $fullPath; if ($exists){ ... } } `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is this:

```
$path = "c:\temp"
$destFolder = "C:\" 
$subFolder = "\folder c\folder d\" 
$file = "file.txt" 

$childItems = Get-ChildItem $path | select -first 10 | Sort-Object -Property CreationTime -Descending

forEach ($item in $childItems) 
{
    $fullPath = Join-Path -Path $item.FullName -ChildPath "$subFolder$file" 
    if (Test-Path -Path $fullPath)
    {
        Copy-Item -Path $fullPath -Destination $destFolder
    }
}
```